# Multiple access read and write on database with titan

Tags: database, titan, tinkerpop

I use titan and database Akiban Persistit. I want know, how the database behaves when multiple access writing and reading.

It is a blocking state? Or what can I expect from it and what should I be careful?

Thanks so much for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persistit, like all Titan storage backends, supports concurrent access. Have a look at the parallel unit tests and their performance to get a feel for the exact performance characteristics.

However, note that Persistit will be moved out of the main Titan codebase into an experimental repository due to the recent lack of development on the project until further notice. I'd encourage you to consider using a single/embedded instance of Cassandra or BDB instead in the near future.